# Convart varchar to date format with a twist

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I have a data column which is in a datetime format. The date is shown like this:

```
 2013-09-07 00:00:00.000; 
 2012-12-09 00:00:00.000; 
 2013-08-19 00:00:00.000;
```

I want the date to be like this

```
 26-JUN-13; 
 08-FEB-12; 
 28-NOV-12;
```

I used following query:

```
select  [003 AccptReg].[dbo].[SysDB].[statCngDate_sys] from [003 AccptReg].[dbo].[SysDB] 
        where [statCngDate_sys]= convert(datetime,left([statCngDate_sys],10),103)
```

But it shows following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

What am I doing wrong?

Also do I have to keep the date column in datetime format rather than in varchar format to search a range of dates?

Comment: are the values really separated by a semicolon?

Comment: @491243: no. entered ";" so that others can understand it as a separate row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50),(CONVERT(DATETIME,'2013-09-07 00:00:00.000')),106)
```

you don't need to convert into datetime as your column must be in same format

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), ' ', '-'))
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```